# Modify POST request in mod_perl2

Tags: perl, apache2, mod-perl2, http-post

Does anyone know how to access/modify the POST request data using mod_perl2.
IN GET method one can get/set the request QUERY string:

```
  $args      = $r->args();
  $prev_args = $r->args($new_args);
```

How to get/set the request QUERY string in POST method ?

Answer (score 5):

Get POST parameters with [`Apache2::Request::param`](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Request#param).

To set, first get an `APR::Request::Param::Table` object from the [`body`](http://p3rl.org/Apache2::Request#body) method. Re[`bless`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) it into an [`APR::Table`](http://p3rl.org/APR::Table) object, then use its methods to manipulate the data.

Answer (score 1):

I use this mod_perl2 code snippet to successfully parse out a form's field value submitted via POST method:

```
use CGI;

my $req = CGI->new($r);
my $field_value = $req->param('form_field');
```

If you don't `use CGI;` as illustrated above, and instead, use the following code:

```
my $req = Apache2::Request->new($r);
my $field_value = $req->param('form_field');
```

You'll probably succeed in GET method. However, while getting request via POST method, in my case, I got into infinite loop of some king of 'prefetching filter.c(270) error' and the request will never return.