# How to modify post request content using mod_perl

Tags: perl, mod-perl, mod-perl2

How to modify post request content using mod_perl's filter/handler?

I can read request content in PerlResponseHandler but how do I "attach" modified content back into request?

Also, I don't want to do this in PerlResponseHandler as I want requested resource to handle response generation part.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083367/modify-post-request-in-mod-perl2

Comment: Thanks Daxim. To access Request script, I'll need to download CPAN's libapreq2-2.12 library. I'll give it a try.

Comment: However I think there must be some way in standard library to read POST data. Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to install libapreq2-2.12 library in mod_perl/perl (I am using indigoampp all in one Apache HTTP Server).

If I copy individual pm files at respective locations, it gives following error:

Comment: [Mon Nov 29 12:24:58 2010] [error] APR/Request/Param.pm did not return a true value at d:/indigoampp/perl-5.12.1/site/lib/Apache2/Request.pm line 2.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at d:/indigoampp/perl-5.12.1/site/lib/Apache2/Request.pm line 2.\nCompilation failed in require at d:/indigoampp/perl-5.12.1/site/lib/MyApache2/Test4.pm line 6.\nBEGIN failed--compilation aborted at d:/indigoampp/perl-5.12.1/site/lib/MyApache2/Test4.pm line 6.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 2) line 2.

Comment: Is there any other way to install it (without manually copying pm files) so I can make use of Request script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `use Apache2::RequestIO` and from `my ($r) = @_;` you can do a `$r->print();`

a `PerlResponseHandler` can not modify request data, but even if it could what would be the point.  Only a `PerlInputFilterHandler` can do that as it filters input before it gets to a response.

The only thing after a response handler is the Output Filters, Log Handler, and the Cleanup Handler.

```
package MyFilter;

use strict;

use base qw(Apache::Filter);
use Apache2::Const qw(OK);

sub handler: FilterRequestHandler {
  my ($f) = @_;
  while($f->read(my $buf, 1024)) {
    # do something with $buf
    $f->print($buf);
  }
  return OK;
}

1;
```

Important to know, that you will get data in chunks.  When you read you may or may not get the whole posted in a single call.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. However the print() function in RequestIO script is used to send data to the client. I am not clear what it means but how can I read POST data using RequestIO? Also, how can I update it? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is, that a PerlResponseHandler is the end of the line for POST data.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy for response. I got that the request can be modifed in PerlInputFilterHandler but can I do that without Apache2::Request module? As I am facing some issues in installing that module.

Comment: What is Apache2::Request?  Never used it before.  I use Apache2::RequestRec and Apache2::RequestIO.

Comment: Apache2::Request is CPAN's module which makes getting post request data real easy.

Comment: That might be your problem then, in a filter you do not have access to the entire post.

Comment: Thanks very much Jeremy. The above code works great in PerlInputFilterHandler.

Answer (score 0):

This code also works -

```
  package MyApache2::Test7;

  use strict;
  use warnings;

  use base qw(Apache2::Filter);

  use Apache2::Connection ();
  use APR::Brigade ();
  use APR::Bucket ();

  use Apache2::Const -compile => 'OK';
  use APR::Const     -compile => ':common';

use Apache2::Log ();

  sub handler : FilterRequestHandler {

Apache2::ServerRec->log_error("f*** starts");


      my ($f, $bb, $mode, $block, $readbytes) = @_; 
      my $c = $f->c;
      my $bb_ctx = APR::Brigade->new($c->pool, $c->bucket_alloc);
      my $rv = $f->next->get_brigade($bb_ctx, $mode, $block, $readbytes);
      return $rv unless $rv == APR::Const::SUCCESS;

      while (!$bb_ctx->is_empty) {
          my $b = $bb_ctx->first;

          if ($b->is_eos) {
              $bb->insert_tail($b);
              last;
          }

          my $len = $b->read(my $data);

Apache2::ServerRec->log_error($len);

          #$b = APR::Bucket->new($bb->bucket_alloc, lc $data) if $len;

          #$b->remove;
          #$bb->insert_tail($b);

Apache2::ServerRec->log_error($data);

Apache2::ServerRec->log_error("f*** ends");

$bb_ctx->cleanup;

      }

      return Apache2::Const::OK;
  }

  1;
```

Comment: You should also be able to "print STDERR" to go to the log file.